# Can't Install Ember-CLI without sudo

Tags: ember.js

```
npm install -g ember-cli


npm ERR! Error: Attempt to unlock ember-cli, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR!     at unlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:44:11)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local.js:30:5)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local.js:47:20
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:30:7
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:167:38
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-61-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ahmed
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ahmed/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

when installing using sudo, then getting problem in creating new app.

```
sudo npm install -g ember-cli
/usr/local/bin/ember -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/couch-login requires request@'~2.9.202' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.30.0
ember-cli@0.0.44 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── js-string-escape@1.0.0
├── broccoli-writer@0.1.1 (rsvp@3.0.13, quick-temp@0.1.2)
└── yam@0.0.14 (lodash@2.4.1, findup@0.1.5, fs-extra@0.8.1)
ahmed@shivank-Vostro-2420:~$ ember -v
version: 0.0.44
node: 0.10.31
npm: 1.4.26
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all remove node completely

```
$ rm -rf ~/.npm ~/.nvm
```

Use NVM to manage node version...

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.17.1/install.sh | bash
$ source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
//add this line to my ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.zshrc
```

Adding source in profile using nano:

`$ nano ~/.profile`

*Go to bottom of the file and add this line:*

`source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

`Then hit CTR+X and press Y to save`

*same for others...*

Use stable version of node

```
$ nvm install 0.10.32
$ nvm use 0.10.32
$ nvm alias default 0.10.32
```

Once you’ve installed Node, you’ll need to install the Ember CLI globally with:

```
$ npm install -g ember-cli
```

This will give you access to the ember command-line runner.

You’ll need to install Bower, a package manager that keeps your front-end dependencies (including JQuery, Ember, and QUnit) up to date. This is as easy as running:

```
$ npm install -g bower
```

This will give you access to the bower command-line runner.

Now you can run enberCLI commands.

Cheers.

Comment: Will this work on Ubuntu? What with all the nodejs-legacy drama?

Comment: I works on Ubuntu, but every time I restart the terminal node is not present anymore. I have to install it. Is it the expected behavior ?

Comment: @user3568719,  you need to add `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.zshrc as per the instructions.

Comment: I have a new machine and can't get ember-cli to install. I have node v4.1 is it because it's an unstable build of node?